# .htaccess mod_rewrite mindblock

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, query-string

I've been having trouble with the ModRewrite on how to appropriately hide query string parameters. Basically something like this..

from:

```
http://localhost/index.php?page=news&=request=somepage&id=100&sort=asc
```

to:

```
http://localhost/news/somepage/id/asc
```

I've attempted to do different variations with it but to no success. For now I make do with revealing query paramaters from the url which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

in `.htaccess` file write:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&=request=$2&id=$3&sort=$4 [L]
```

Also for better using with images, stylesheets, scripts etc. I recommend to add `<base href="index.php">` in `<head>` tag at all pages in your site.

Comment: Forgot to mention that some assets wont load like images and stylesheets because of the directories (I've done the same but with a different RewriteRule)..

Comment: I've edited my answer, try to add RewriteBase in your .htaccess file

Comment: <base href="index.php"> actually worked for me without declaring RewriteBase, although for it to work relatively I will have to work on adopting <base/> for deep addresses. Thanks :)